# Extract values by key from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

Given this nested dictionary, how could I print all the "phone" values using a for loop?

```
people = {
    'Alice': {
        'phone': '2341',
        'addr': '87 Eastlake Court'
        },

    'Beth': {
        'phone': '9102',
        'addr': '563 Hartford Drive'
        },

    'Randy': {
        'phone': '4563',
        'addr': '93 SW 43rd'
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything. I can only figure out how to print a single value (which works), but when setting up a for loop, I get a "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode" error.

Comment: The error you reference should be included in your post.

Comment: If you've made attempts at the problem, you should include what you've tried and the specific problems (including exceptions and/or full stacktraces) that you are having.

Answer (score 10):

```
for d in people.values():
    print d['phone']
```

Comment: Why even using _ and .items() when you could use .values()?

Comment: @Apero Because I was being dense! You're absolutely right. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the values and then use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method, if you want to handle the missing keys, or a simple indexing to access the nested values. Also, for the sake of optimization you can do the whole process in a list comprehension :

```
>>> [val.get('phone') for val in people.values()]
['4563', '9102', '2341']
```

Comment: Who the heck is downvoting everything?!

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension

```
>>> [people[i]['phone'] for i in people]
['9102', '2341', '4563']
```

Or if you'd like to use a `for` loop.

```
l = []
for person in people:
    l.append(people[person]['phone'])

>>> l
['9102', '2341', '4563']
```

Comment: Why even bother with the second option when the first is the way to go. BTW I do not understand the downvote.... maybe because you should use: [people[i].get('phone', 'N/A') for i in people] but it still answered the OP's question

Comment: The OP's question asked how to do this, specifically using a `for` loop so I thought I'd throw that option in too. The downvote is because people get upset at underdefined questions and go downvote everything in a thread, including answers. Frankly, I know a downvote is coming, but I am here to help people out, so generally I will answer the question if it isn't way too much work (e.g. "How can I make my own STL?")